# x raised to the power of x raised to the power of logarithm base 3 x

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

Have a question that has me a little stumped. I know that this equation:$$x^\left(log_3x + x^\left(log_3x\right)\right) \neq 162$$

Simplifies to:
$$x^\left(log_3x\right) \neq 81$$

My question is how exactly did they come to the second equation. I know from there it simplifies to:
$$(3^\left(log_3x\right))^\left(log_3x\right) \neq 3^4$$

And then:
$$(log_4x)^2 \neq 4$$

Comment: i reelly don't understand what you mean?

Comment: how was the first equation simplified to $$x^\left(log_3x\right) \neq 81$$

Comment: Um, if x = 9 then $x^{\log_3 x} = 9^2= 81$ but $x^{\log_3 x + x^{\log_3 x}} =9^{2 + 9^2} \ne  162$.  So doesn't follow.

Comment: What is the value of $x$ ?

Comment: @fleablood and if $x=16$ then $(\log_4 x)^2=2^2=4$ but $x^{\left(log_3x\right)} = 16^{\left(log_3 16\right)} \neq 81$